# FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value training/Adam/*

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am working on a simple keras model, and I want to use some callbacks such as Tensorboard and ReduceLROnPlateau, but I got error like:

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value training/Adam/Variable_81

model works in tensorflow 1.14, python 3.6, keras 2.2.4

I have tried keras.backends.get_session().run(***initializers), but still the same error shown.

```
log_dir  ='logs/'
data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=0.2,
                width_shift_range=0.05,
                height_shift_range=0.05,
                shear_range=0.05,
                zoom_range=0.05,
                horizontal_flip=True,
                fill_mode='nearest')  

myGene=trainGenerator(2,'data/membrane/train','image','label',data_gen_args,save_to_dir = None)
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(log_dir + "ep{epoch:03d}-loss{loss:.3f}.h5",
    monitor='loss', save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, period=1)
logging = TensorBoard(log_dir=log_dir)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.1, patience=3, verbose=1)

early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=1)

model = unet()

model.fit_generator(myGene,steps_per_epoch=5,epochs=10,callbacks=[logging, reduce_lr, early_stopping, model_checkpoint])

##########################
model codes, another .py file
##########################

from keras.models import *

from keras.layers import *

from keras.optimizers import *

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

from keras import backend as keras


def unet(pretrained_weights = None,input_size = (256,256,1)):
    inputs = Input(input_size)
    conv1
    ......
    conv10 = Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'sigmoid')(conv9)

    model = Model(input = inputs, output = conv10)

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 
    'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model
```

early_stopping callback works well, maybe it is irrelevant with Adam. All I want is add some callbacks functions into a keras model.

or does it matter with model.fit_generator?

Comment: error comes from line below, the origin version should be:
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau

Comment: the code block above should be the correct version, sorry for misleading....